# mule how to get http header values from postman rest client

Tags: mule, mule-studio

```
<flow  name="getDetails">
    <http:inbound-endpoint doc:description="This endpoint receives an HTTP message." doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="getDetails"/>
    <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON" mimeType="text/json"  ignoreBadInput="true"/> 
    <logger message="xml to json output #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

      <logger message=" custom header username ... #[message.outboundProperties.get('http.headers.username')]" level="INFO" />
      <logger message=" custom header username ... #[message.inboundProperties.get('http.headers.username')]" level="INFO" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  address="http://localhost:8081/callReservation" method="POST" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```

thru postman rest client (chrome) using , **form-data , x-www-form-urlencoded.**

I set   header values like
**http.headers.username=mule 
http.headers.password=mule**

In mule `**<logger message=" custom header username ... #[message.outboundProperties.get('http.headers.username')]" level="INFO" />**`

it shows null value. any valuable suggestions are welcome

Comment: Which mule version are you using? Could you share your flow?

Comment: i added my code above . pls look in to that

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use key name as http.headers.username. Please use key as username and values as mule. You should then be able to access the username property from your inbound properties using MEL like #[message.inboundProperties['username']]

Comment: I added my code above .pls look in to that. I got like error like below

com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1] (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException). Message payload is of type: String

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be from your

```
<json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON" mimeType="text/json"  ignoreBadInput="true"/>
```

which is giving you the following exception :- `com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<' at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1] (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException).`

Just use the following expression :- 
`#[message.inboundProperties.username]` or `#[message.inboundProperties['username']]` in a logger and place it **just after** your `<http:inbound-endpoint/>` and you will get the value.